# Introduce a new WFE in the existing SharePoint 2007 Farm?

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, deployment

We would like to introduce a new WFE in the existing SharePoint 2007 Farm, due to the business requirement, which already has 8WFEs and separate servers for Index, Query & admin. what would be the best approach to follow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tell a bit more about the farm setup? Especially regarding SQL server.

A rule of thumb is that you should not have more than 5 WFE per SQL server instance. Going beyond that the WFE will put too much stress on the SQL server, and actually degrade performance. I also seem to remember something about a support limit of 8 WFE, but im not certain.

EDIT: ok i found the soft limit for WFE on TechNet:

Web server/database server ratio: 8* Web servers per database server
 The scale out factor is dependent upon the mix of operations.

Comment: Farm Configuration: 
1. Two Clusters (Active + Active) 
2. 4 WFEs / cluster 
3. 3 Instance of SQL Server 

Let me know if need any other information